# Chart isn't working if i don't select a cell

Tags: vba, excel

Why does this line below doesn't work?

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(204, xlColumnClustered).Select
```

but this one do

```
graphe_clos.Cells(2, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(204, xlColumnClustered).Select
```

And i intend to create multiple chart and pivot table on the same sheet so do i need to always specify a cell?

Comment: Why use `select` anyhow? Do a `With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(204, xlColumnClustered)` or assign the result to a variable.

Comment: i use select because i have to do this
`With ActiveChart
      .ClearToMatchStyle
      .ChartStyle = 257
      .HasTitle = True
      .ChartTitle.Text = " Nombre d'évènement"
      .ShowValueFieldButtons = False
      .ShowLegendFieldButtons = False
End With`

Comment: No, it's not necessary to  do this on `ActiveChart`.

Comment: and how should i do it?

Comment: if i do `With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(204, xlColumnClustered)` it's asking me to assign it to a variable, it's better to create a variable for it then using `.select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (had to add `.Chart` in the `with` statement)

```
with ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(204, xlColumnClustered).Chart
    .ClearToMatchStyle 
    .ChartStyle = 257 
    .HasTitle = True 
    .ChartTitle.Text = " Nombre d'évènement" 
end with
```

However, the properties `.ShowValueFieldButtons` and `.ShowValueFieldButtons` are not valid (I think they are valid only for PivotCharts). It gives error messages no matter if or if not using `ActiveChart`.

As a general advice: Read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: hmmm interesting, In my my macro`.ShowValueFieldButtons` is working

Answer (score 1):

Use .AddChart instead of .AddChart2. That works for me. Then later you can edit the chart properties in a With block.